# Split Url from the rest of the data using a '/' delimeter

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm pretty new to C# and I am trying split some data into a string array using the `/` delimiter. The data comes as:

> 1/London/https://media.timeout.com/images/100644443/image.jpg

I would like to have:`1` and `London` and `https://media.timeout.com/images/100644443/image.jpg` separately.

but when I do this:

```
var x = obj.Split('/');
```

the URL is also split into parts obviously. Is there any workaround to this besides changing the delimiter?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx What's wrong with `count = 3`? *count
Type: System.Int32
The maximum number of substrings to return.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var someString = "1/London/https://media.timeout.com/images/100644443/image.jpg";
```

Use `IndexOf` method to get the index of `https`:

```
var index = someString.IndexOf("https")
```

Then you can split the string from the beginning up until the index of `https`:

```
var splitParts = someString.Substring(0, index - 1).Split('/');
```

And the url will be after the index of `https`:

```
var urlPart = someString.Substring(index);
```

Comment: Thank you it's exactly what i was looking for. Nice and simple. :)

Answer (score 1):

`obj.Split(new[] {'/'}, 3)`

> ## [String.Split Method (Char[], Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> ...
>
> count
>   Type: System.Int32
>   The maximum number of substrings to return.
>
> ...
>
> If there are more than count substrings in this instance, the first count minus 1 substrings are returned in the first count minus 1 elements of the return value, and the remaining characters in this instance are returned in the last element of the return value.

Comment: I already accepted an answer, so all i can do is to say a very big thank you for this. Best and shortest way!

Answer (score 0):

You could you `IndexOf` to find the first and then second occurence of a '/'.

Something like this (not verified in editor):

```
s1 = obj.Substring(0, obj.IndexOf("/"));
s2 = s1.Substring(0, s1.IndexOf("/"));
s3 = s2.Substring(0, s2.IndexOf("/"));

String[] output = new String[] { s1, s2, s3 };
```

This isn't pretty but I don't know another way to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = obj.Split('/');
StringBuilder partA = new StringBuilder();
string partB = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in arr) {
 if (item.ToLower().StartsWith("http")) {
  partB = obj.Replace(partA.ToString(),string.Empty);
  break;
 }
 partA.Append(item);
 partA.Append("/");
}
```

Or

```
  var partA = obj.Split('/',2);
  var partB = obj.Replace(partA.ToString(),string.Empty);
```

Comment: Ignore flagging - trying to delete this but can't on phone

Comment: Also works but only after i changed the following:
partB = obj.Replace(partA.toString(), string.Empty); Thank you for your answer.